# I am getting an error with incident no. when I am creating storage azure integration in Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-connector

SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 370001:1831050371; incident 8133910.

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a support ticket to Snowflake with account details, query id etc. They will assist with the reason behind the incident. You can raise the ticket from the community portal.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Also, you can check if there is any outage from Snowflake during the time when your query hit the incident
https://status.snowflake.com/

Regards,
Sujan